# Selecting data between dates - "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, oledbcommand

I have put following code to extract data from Microsoft Access database to populate a Combobox in VB.NET

```
Private Sub PopulateList()
    If RBDura.Checked = True Then
        CmbTstNo.Items.Clear()
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connstring
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        str = "SELECT DISTINCT Test_Code FROM Table_Durability_Test WHERE Log_Date BETWEEN " & DtFrom.Text & " and " & DtTo.Text & ""
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            CmbTstNo.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
        End While
        myConnection.Close()
        CmbTstNo.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

However when the code is run, I get an error "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Please Guide..

Comment: Dont glue strings together to make SQL.  Use SQL parmeters so you can pass the correct data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL string you have is `"SELECT DISTINCT Test_Code FROM Table_Durability_Test WHERE Log_Date BETWEEN " & DtFrom.Text & " and " & DtTo.Text & ""`

If you are entering a text or string to a database using SQL, **you have to surround each text entry with single quotes** so your SQL string would look like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT Test_Code FROM Table_Durability_Test WHERE Log_Date BETWEEN 'Value of DtFrom.Text' and 'Value of DtTo.Text'`

Notice that I have surrounded the `Value of DtTo.Text` and `Value of DtFrom.Text` with **single quotes**.